# Cannot put an id on an unsorted list in a Modal Generated By a Jquery Plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

Below is an html in a modal generated by the Jquery plugin file I included:

```
<div class="photobooth">
    <div class="blind"></div>
    <canvas ></canvas>
    <div class="warning notSupported"></div>
    <div class="warning noWebcam"></div>
    <ul>
        <li title="hue" class="hue"></li>
        <li title="saturation" class="saturation"></li>
        <li title="brightness" class="brightness"></li>
        <li title="crop" class="crop"></li>
        <li title="take picture" class="trigger"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've been using the code below to put an id to my  tag in runtime :

```
var ul = document.querySelector('.photobooth > ul');
ul.id = 'someId';
```

But it throws an error saying:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null     myid.js?      njl6m7:190 (anonymous function)
```

What will I do to put an id in my  tag? I suspect that by the time my script code is executed, the modal html is not yet loaded. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is it possible that the modal is not in the DOM (not being shown, or set to display:none) while the script tries to set the id? This would cause that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure about all of the details, but what I did was copied the code you have over and included a script tag with that JavaScript. so the HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="photobooth">
            <div class="blind"></div>
            <canvas ></canvas>
            <div class="warning notSupported"></div>
            <div class="warning noWebcam"></div>
            <ul>
                <li title="hue" class="hue"></li>
                <li title="saturation" class="saturation"></li>
                <li title="brightness" class="brightness"></li>
                <li title="crop" class="crop"></li>
                <li title="take picture" class="trigger"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript file (`main.js`) looks like this:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('.photobooth > ul');
ul.id = 'someId';
```

to fix your problem, I moved the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the `<body>` tag. this will run `main.js` after the body has loaded, like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="photobooth">
            <div class="blind"></div>
            <canvas ></canvas>
            <div class="warning notSupported"></div>
            <div class="warning noWebcam"></div>
            <ul>
                <li title="hue" class="hue"></li>
                <li title="saturation" class="saturation"></li>
                <li title="brightness" class="brightness"></li>
                <li title="crop" class="crop"></li>
                <li title="take picture" class="trigger"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script src='main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the jQuery equivalent of putting the script tag at the end of the body, from my understanding, is using `$(document).ready(callback)` or `$(window).load(callback)`, which do different things.

the difference is: `$(document).ready` waits for the DOM to load but does NOT wait for any graphics (images, etc.), while `$(window).load(callback)` waits for everything to finish. so if you wanted to use either of these, your `main.js` file would become:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ul = document.querySelector('.photobooth > ul');
    ul.id = 'someId';
});
```

and your script tag would be in the `<head>` tag. hopefully this works out!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out which plugin you are using...

And since you are using jQuery, you can do:

```
$('#example').photobooth();
$('.photobooth > ul').attr('id', 'someId');
```

That will apply that ID to the first ul in the photobooth widget that is generated on load. (where '#example' is the ID of the container for your photobooth widget)

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwells/afsfsbw5/)